# Events on RadPropertyGrid similar to PropertyValue Changed

Tags: telerik

Is there any event on `RadPropertyGrid` similar to `PropertyValueChanged` event on `winform` propertyGrid.

I tried to use InotifyPropertyChanged event on the property and implemented the logic what I did in PropertyValue Changed event in winforms in the Set code block of the property.But I need to refresh PropertyGrid because telerik people said once we change the Browsable attribute of the Property,it will be reflected in the grid only after Reload Method on the propertygrid is called. I need to access the PropertyGrid to do that.I think I can access it only in one of the event of propertygrid.So I need one event where I can Refresh the data of the grid once I change the PropertyValue.

Regards,

Nagasree.

Comment: Put what you try to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per telerik there is no direct **propertyvaluechangd** event. If you want to refresh you have to create a property in viewmodel and based on the property value change you can call method on control using the triggers as shown below

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<ei:DataTrigger   Binding="{Binding IsRefreshed}" Value="True">
    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ReloadData" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=PropertyGrid}"/>
</ei:DataTrigger>
```